# Set text in textview very blurry

Tags: android

I'm looking into methods of completely blurring a text in a textview. Read, completely unreadable (pixelate). The methods i'm using now are using shadows. But this seems very inefficient. Anyone who has a better solution?

Comment: Give the textview's background the same color as the text ;)

Comment: not possible...you should see the spaces between words...

Comment: Should it be pixelated for some fancy UI ? Why not just replace the text characters with asterisk (*) as in password ?

Comment: Does it have to be a textview? Could it be an ImageView in which you put the text, blurred if needed?

Answer (score 35):

I did not like the Paint method used in the other answers. The below code is working for me with the radius calculated depending on the font size and applying it directly on the TextView.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
     yourTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
float radius = yourTextView.getTextSize() / 3;
BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
yourTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @theczechsensation Is there a way to change to change the blur color from the default white?

Comment: @Crocodile You can use `yourTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(null)` to clear the blur.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to use [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) instead of `TextView` and draw a text with blur.
There is a lot of method using [BlurMaskFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter.html) and you can use this like that :

```
paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(float radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur style));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below methods:

1. Whenever you want to show blurry text, use a specialized font for
   your `TextView`, added to asset folder of your project.
2. Try setting a transparent color[`#00ffffff`] to your text and give some shadow to it.

I hope one of the above method helps.

Comment: Solution 2 isn't possible, when setting the text to a transparent color no shadow is generated

Comment: What is a 'specialized' font ?

Comment: Yes. How about trying out 1st solution?

Comment: By 'specialized' font I meant a custom font which serves this particular purpose. May be one like this: http://www.fontspace.com/uzim/thundershower

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to obfuscate the text you can try using [TransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod) of TextView.

Here you have an example, is not a blurring effect but may help: https://gist.github.com/RicardAparicio/bdd6cd30410f9431e1da238202a1dfa9