# How to undo a mask filter blur on a TextView in Android

Tags: android, mask, blur

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39313269/682778) to blur some text:

```
    val radius = msgText.getTextSize() / 3
    val mTextFilter = BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
    msgTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(mTextFilter)
```

...at some point I wanted to undo the blur so I tried:

```
msgTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(null)
```

but that does **not** clear the blur from the text despite its description:

```
package android.graphics;

...

public class Paint {

...
/**
     * Set or clear the maskfilter object.
     * <p />
     * Pass null to clear any previous maskfilter.
     * As a convenience, the parameter passed is also returned.
     *
     * @param maskfilter May be null. The maskfilter to be installed in the
     *                   paint
     * @return           maskfilter
     */
    public MaskFilter setMaskFilter(MaskFilter maskfilter) {
        long maskfilterNative = 0;
        if (maskfilter != null) {
            maskfilterNative = maskfilter.native_instance;
        }
        nSetMaskFilter(mNativePaint, maskfilterNative);
        mMaskFilter = maskfilter;
        return maskfilter;
    }
...
}
```

So I am confused. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `msgTextView.invalidate()` right after clearing the filter?

Comment: Try this and let me know,
`mTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);`
 // Clear any previous MaskFilter
`mTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(null);`

Comment: Thanks! They both work! I'll go with the answer from @Radhey though as I am already setting mTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null); when I am setting the blur. If you add it as an answer I accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is perfect just you need to add these lines as per your need!

To set Blur effect

```
val radius = msgText.getTextSize() / 3
val mTextFilter = BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
msgTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(mTextFilter)
```

To remove Blur effect

```
msgTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
// Clear any previous 
MaskFilter mTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(null);
```

To apply inner Blur

```
applyBlurMaskFilter(mTextView, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.INNER);
```

To apply outer Blur

```
applyBlurMaskFilter(mTextView, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER);
```

To apply normal Blur

```
applyBlurMaskFilter(mTextView, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
```

To apply solid Blur

```
applyBlurMaskFilter(mTextView, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.SOLID);
```

here `applyBlurMaskFilter()` is user defined method.

Comment: In my api 24 emulator, after blurring a textview, any textviews in the app got stayed in a blurry mode. It is not applying to the current textview but all of them.
There is a caution in getPaint() documentation:
/**
     * Gets the {@link TextPaint} used for the text.
     * Use this only to consult the Paint's properties and not to change them.
     * @return The base paint used for the text.
     */

Comment: post your code. hope you had apply correct reference of your TextView. try to crosscheck in real device too.

Comment: msgTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
adding this before setting the blurmask fixed the problem. Thanks