# Blur specific words in TextView

Tags: android

I have an Android app, inside I have 3 TextViews in a vertical LinearLayout.  I want to blur parts of the TextViews by a String array containing the words that should be blurred. The TextViews looks like this.

[image]

In this example, I want to blur all the occurrences of the words "than" and "third".

I currently blur the text using a `BlurMaskFilter` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39313269/3731180). However, it blurs the whole text in the TextView, and I want to blur specific words only.

My solution was replacing the 3 TextViews by 3 horizontal LinearLayouts and loop through the text of the TextViews, when reaching a word that needs to be blurred, split the `TextView` to three TextViews: start, blurred part, end. In our example, it will be "this is the", "third"(blurred), "textview" for the third `TextView`.

The problem I get can be seen here:

[image]

So as you can see, when the text reaches more than one row, the second line won't start from the start of the screen, as it is a `LinearLayout` and the view before it takes some space. What I want to achieve is being able to cut a TextView in the middle of a line, even if it is a multiline TextView, add another TextView right next to it and blur it, and add the continuation of the text afterward, and it'll start the next line from the beginning. I don't know any layout type that will fit these needs, nor a way of achieving it in a different way.

My current code to achieve the state shown in the last picture:

Activity --> create the texts, and append them to the layouts:

```
LinearLayout linear0 = findViewById(R.id.testlinear0);
LinearLayout linear1 = findViewById(R.id.testlinear1);
LinearLayout linear2 = findViewById(R.id.testlinear2);

TextView firstTextView = new TextView(this);
firstTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
setHtmlText(firstTextView, "adsada");
firstTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.WikiTextViewStyle);

TextView aaa = new TextView(this);
aaa.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
setHtmlText(aaa, HelperClass.levelsContent.get(levelName)[0]);
aaa.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.WikiTextViewStyle);

TextView secondTextView = new TextView(this);
secondTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
setHtmlText(secondTextView, HelperClass.levelsContent.get(levelName)[1]);
secondTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.WikiTextViewStyle);

TextView thirdTextView = new TextView(this);
thirdTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
setHtmlText(thirdTextView, HelperClass.levelsContent.get(levelName)[2]);
thirdTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.WikiTextViewStyle);


thirdTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
float radius = thirdTextView.getTextSize() / 3;
BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
thirdTextView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);

linear0.addView(firstTextView);
linear0.addView(aaa);
linear1.addView(secondTextView);
linear2.addView(thirdTextView);
```

layout -->

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/testlinear0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/testlinear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/testlinear2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set text in textview very blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586681/set-text-in-textview-very-blurry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perhaps use a [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) and mark the portion of text you want to be blurred using a [`MaskFilterSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/MaskFilterSpan)? For example:

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with blur mask");
MaskFilter blurMask = new BlurMaskFilter(5f, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
string.setSpan(new MaskFilterSpan(blurMask), 10, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(string);
```